# Changing a model of a QML ListView doesn't change the corresponding delegate

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

Below I create a ListView with a delegate which contains a CheckBox whose `checked` property is bound to the model's `checked` role. When the delegate is clicked, I want to toggle the CheckBox state by changing the model's `checked` property. But the binding between `checkBox.checked` and `model.checked` works only the first time the user clicks on the delegate. After that, `checkBox` is always checked, independent of the `model.checked` value. The result is that the user cannot uncheck the checkbox and I do not want this.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ListView { id: listView
    height: 100
    width: 100

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { checked: false }
        ListElement { checked: false }
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: listView.width
        implicitHeight: checkBox.implicitHeight * 1.3

        CheckBox { id: checkBox
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: index + 1
            checked: model.checked
        }

        MouseArea { id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                var item = listView.model.get(index);

                console.log('old model.checked:', model.checked);
                item.checked = !item.checked;
                console.log('new model.checked:', model.checked);

                console.log('checkBox.checked:', checkBox.checked);
                console.log('something went wrong:', model.checked !== checkBox.checked);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem in my code and how can I make the delegate work like a normal CheckBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a reported bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31627.

Using the walkaround described in the comments under that bug report makes the checkbox from my code work normally. I removed the `checked: model.checked` line and added the following code to the Rectangle delegate:

```
Binding {
    target: checkBox
    property: 'checked'
    value: model.checked
}
```

Comment: You're right, I could reproduce the bug in a minimal project without any model: https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/7979803